# How can I use the same click event to trigger fadeIn and fadeOut?

Tags: jquery

I have this listener on a person:

```
$person.on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.persondata').fadeIn('fast', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

This fades an overlay on top of the user. Works great.

Now I have an "x" button that when the user clicks, I want to fade everything back out.

```
$('.close').click(function (e) {
    if ($('.persondata:visible')) {
        $(this).closest('.persondata').fadeOut('fast', function (e) {
           // stop everything. dont fade back in!
        });
    }
});
```

Which, works great too. But, once the element has faded out, it will fade back in again because of the top click event.

Is there a way to just stop everything after I have faded out the cover?  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel event bubbling up to parent nodes.

```
$('.close').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   ....
}
```

Comment: I was using `e. stopPropagation();` Just needed to add `preventDefault` I guess. Thank you for your time!